# Posting to UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-handler, ui-thread

I would like to create a new thread in `onCreate` and communicate with the UI thread using `post` on a `View`. However, the `post`ed statements never seem to be run. Here's a small example:

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView    
import kotlin.concurrent.*
import org.jetbrains.anko.*

class MainActivity: Activity(), AnkoLogger {
  protected override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val view = TextView(this)
    setContentView(view)

    thread() {
      info("before post")
      view.post({ info("inside post") })
      info("after post")
    }
  }
}
```

Looking at the log, I can only see `before post` and `after post`, but never `inside post`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: mb something in the `info()` implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying issue actually has nothing to do with Kotlin.

The problem is that `View.post()` only schedules its work successfully on the main thread if the view is *currently* attached to the view hierarchy.  The final attach of the view doesn't happen at the time of `setContentView()`.  It happens some time later.

In the event that the subject view of the `post()` is not currently attached (as is the case shown in the problem), the `View` creates a `RunQueue` for the current thread (stored as a thread local) and schedules the work on that `RunQueue`.

So, the problem for the given sample is as follows.  Since `View.post()` is not called on the main thread, it will create a new `RunQueue` for the current, non-main thread without checking to see if it's being directed by a `Looper` (as is the main thread). This means the scheduled `Runnable` essentially goes into a `RunQueue` that is not processed until a `Looper` starts.  In the case shown here, that `Looper` is never started, the new thread terminates, and the work is never executed.

If the new thread with `post` was delayed until after the view was attached, for example, when a click is registered on it, the `post` will likely be able to schedule the work on the main thread.  But that's not the case here since the post occurs 1) before the view is attached, and 2) on a different non-`Looper` thread that terminates immediately.

Comment: What would be the correct time to start the `thread()` without relying on user interaction like the click in your example?

Comment: I would guess during the View's onAttachedToWindow(), or a registered View.OnAttachStateChangeListener.

Comment: Oh and BTW I never thought it'd be Kotlin-specific, but tagged it as Kotlin so that someone who looks at the minimal repro example can figure out what language that is.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by starting the thread itself from a `post`, i.e.

```
view.post({
  thread() {
    info("before post")
    view.post({ info("inside post") })
    info("after post")
  }
})
```

but I would like to understand why I needed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have a look at Handlers. Its a safer way of updating UI objects when performing operations on a different thread. Basically you just have to pass in the handler object to your thread in order to update the Ui

More info here
http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/Handler.html